# Resource in layout taken from another module

Tags: android, layout, resources, multi-module

I have a multimodule project and `android.nonTransitiveRClass=true` in `graddle.properties`

I have two different drawables with similar names `ic_drawable` in different mudules: ModuleA and ModuleB.

When I'm using these resources from code, I specify the target modules R file and get the drawable I need.

ModuleA fragment:

```kotlin
import com.exaple.moduleb.R as MuduleBR
import com.exaple.modulea.R as R
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.contentView.background = 
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, MuduleBR.drawable.ic_drawable, context.theme)
    }
...
```

But in Lyaout I can't specify the module for drawable and can only write like this `background="@drawable/ic_drawable"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawable"
        android:orientation="vertical">
...
```

In designtime layout is rendered with correct drawable, but when I launch my app, I see ModuleB drawable in ModuleA fragment.

What could be wrong?

---

UPD

I was wrong and I cant access the resource needed in code by specifying correct R class.

Seems, that same name resources are overwritten.

Comment: Probably the file behind ic_drawable is also present in ModuleA Project and thus the file in ModuleB is overwritten on packaging.

Comment: Sure it is there. But gradle is set to generate module independed resources and it works from source code.

Comment: AFAIK the setting you show here only makes gradle generate R-Class with scope limited to the current module. But it does not stop the build from replacing resource files.